# Change mat-checkbox value according to its state

Tags: angular-material

I want the mat-checkbox value to have 2 different values, for example:
If it is checked then it equals 1, if it is unchecked it equals 2.

I have no idea on how to do this since there's few little documentation on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Check this StackBlitz: [CheckBox value example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bygt7g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In your HTML file:

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="clicked()">Check me!</mat-checkbox>

{{ checkBoxValue }}
```

In your TS file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  checkBoxValue: number = 1;
  checked: boolean = false;

  clicked() {
    this.checked = !this.checked;

    if (this.checked) 
      this.checkBoxValue = 2;
    else
      this.checkBoxValue = 1;
  }
}
```